# Python gzip fails on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, gzip

This function is based on the Python sample code @ http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html. It runs reliably on Ubuntu 10.04 with its default Python 2.6x. On Ubuntu 11.04, however, the code fails @ writelines().

On one 11.04 machine, the failure message reported "'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'". Another 11.04 machine reported a different message "No module named numpy".

Does anyone know of any missing Python dependencies or other problems on 11.04 that would cause this?

```
def _compress(inp,out):
    import gzip
    f_out = gzip.open(out,'wb')
    f_in = open(inp,'rb')
    f_out.writelines(f_in)
    f_out.close()
    f_in.close()
    os.unlink(inp)
```

Comment: I can tell you that it perfectly works for me on 12.04. Could you make a full script with a test file and paste the full output (and the script)?

Comment: Sorry, xubuntix, I traced the problem to the existence of a non-standard io.py module in the sys.path(). Python's gzip module ignored it on 2.6x (Ubuntu 10.04) but tried to load it on 2.7x (Ubuntu 11.04+). Removing/renaming the io.sys module fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tahoar [solved the problem in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133517/python-gzip-fails-on-ubuntu-11-04#comment174869_133517):

> Sorry, xubuntix, I traced the problem to the existence of a non-standard io.py module in the sys.path(). Python's gzip module ignored it on 2.6x (Ubuntu 10.04) but tried to load it on 2.7x (Ubuntu 11.04+). Removing/renaming the io.sys module fixed the problem. Thanks